# Probability of winning a raffle on the first and second drawing

Tags: probability

If $4$ men and $3$ women are taking part in a raffle, in which $2$ prizes are being offered, what is the probability that the first prize is won by a male and the second prize in won by a female?

Would one just do $(\frac{4}{7} \times \frac{3}{6}) = \frac{2}{7} = 28.57\%$?

Comment: Yes it’s just that

Comment: If they bought one ticket each !